# How to using ruby to match string?

Tags: regex, ruby

I got some strings like above, and I want to get the start time and end time for HHH, I have no idea of how to match the expected string. Is anyone can help me on regular expression to make this come true.

```
AAA

2019-07-13 02:01 - 2019-07-17 01:59 CST (-5)

BBB

2019-07-13 17:01 - 2019-07-17 16:59 AEST (+10)

CCC

2019-07-13 15:01 - 2019-07-17 14:59 CST (+8)

DDD

2019-07-13 15:01 - 2019-07-17 14:59 CST (+8)

EEE

2019-07-13 15:01 - 2019-07-17 14:59 CST (+8)

FFF

2019-07-13 09:01 - 2019-07-17 08:59 CET (+2)

GGG

2019-07-13 09:01 - 2019-07-17 08:59 CET (+2)

HHH

2019-07-13 09:01 - 2019-07-17 08:59 CET (+2)

III

2019-07-13 03:01 - 2019-07-17 02:59 EST (-4)

JJJ

2019-07-13 03:01 - 2019-07-17 02:59 EST (-4)

KKK

2019-07-13 00:01 - 2019-07-16 23:59 PST (-7)

LLL

2019-07-13 15:01 - 2019-07-17 14:59 CST (+8)

MMM

2019-07-13 09:01 - 2019-07-17 08:59 CET (+2)


2019-07-13 07:01 UTC - 2019-07-17 06:59 UTC
```

Comment: Is this one string held by a variable or several strings, each held by a variable or the elements of an array? If so, you should to include the sting(s) in quotes and assign variable(s). If not, is it an image of a text file? If so, are there empty lines between each non-empty line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This expression is likely to extract those desired dates and times right after the `HHH`:

```
(?<=HHH)\s*(\s*\d{4}\s*-\s*\d{2}\s*-\s*\d{2})\s+(.+?)\s+-\s+(\s*\d{4}\s*-\s*\d{2}\s*-\s*\d{2}\s*)\s(.+?)\s+[A-Z]{3}
```

and it can be also much simplified.

The expression is explained on the top right panel of [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/qwI2y1/1/) if you wish to explore/simplify/modify it.

#### Test

```
re = /(?<=HHH)\s*(\s*\d{4}\s*-\s*\d{2}\s*-\s*\d{2})\s+(.+?)\s+-\s+(\s*\d{4}\s*-\s*\d{2}\s*-\s*\d{2}\s*)\s(.+?)\s+[A-Z]{3}/
str = '

2019-07-13 09:01 - 2019-07-17 08:59 CET (+2)

HHH

2019-07-13 09:01 - 2019-07-17 08:59 CET (+2)'

str.scan(re) do |match|
    puts match.to_s
end
```

#### Output

```
["2019-07-13", "09:01", "2019-07-17", "08:59"]
```

Comment: Also a good idea, thanks Emma.

Answer (score 1):

I assume the text is a single string (which may have been read from a file).

```
text =<<END
AAA
2019-07-13 02:01 - 2019-07-17 01:59 CST (-5)
BBB
2019-07-13 17:01 - 2019-07-17 16:59 AEST (+10)
CCC
2019-07-13 15:01 - 2019-07-17 14:59 CST (+8)
DDD
2019-07-13 15:01 - 2019-07-17 14:59 CST (+8)
EEE
2019-07-13 15:01 - 2019-07-17 14:59 CST (+8)
FFF
2019-07-13 09:01 - 2019-07-17 08:59 CET (+2)
GGG
2019-07-13 09:01 - 2019-07-17 08:59 CET (+2)
HHH
2019-07-13 09:01 - 2019-07-17 08:59 CET (+2)
III
2019-07-13 03:01 - 2019-07-17 02:59 EST (-4)
JJJ
2019-07-13 03:01 - 2019-07-17 02:59 EST (-4)
KKK
2019-07-13 00:01 - 2019-07-16 23:59 PST (-7)
LLL
2019-07-13 15:01 - 2019-07-17 14:59 CST (+8)
MMM
2019-07-13 09:01 - 2019-07-17 08:59 CET (+2)
2019-07-13 07:01 UTC - 2019-07-17 06:59 UTC
END
```

We set `target` equal to the line preceding the line of interest.

```
target = 'HHH'
```

We can use the following regular expression.

```
r = /
    ^              # match the beginning of a line
    (?<=           # begin a positive lookbehind
      #{target}    # match the value of target
      \n           # match the end of the line
    )              # end the positive lookbehind
    .+             # match one or more characters
    /x             # free-spacing regex-definition mode
  #=>
    /
    ^
    (?<=
      HHH
      \n
    )
   .+
    /x
```

This is more commonly written as follows:

```
/^(?<=#{target}\n).+/
```

This will extract the desired line:

```
s = text[r]
  #=> "2019-07-13 09:01 - 2019-07-17 08:59 CET (+2)"
```

Now break this up and obtain the desired `Time` objects.

```
require 'time'

f,t,z = s.split /\s-\s|\s+(?=\p{Lu})
  #=> ["2019-07-13 09:01", "2019-07-17 08:59", "CET (+2)"]
z = z[/[+-]\d+/] << '000'
  #=> "+2000" 
start_date, end_date = [f,t].map do |s|
  DateTime.strptime(s+z, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M%Z')
end.map(&:to_time)
  #=> [2019-07-13 09:01:00 +2000, 2019-07-17 08:59:00 +2000]
```

Thus,

```
start_date
  #=> 2019-07-13 09:01:00 +2000
end_date
  #=> 2019-07-17 08:59:00 +2000
```

Comment: For my case: ```/^(?<=#{target}\n\n).+/```

Comment: Re `\n\n` vs `\n`, I did ask you about that in a comment, but you never replied.